# Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.1.1' (111)

Tags: mysql

I am trying to connect to a MariaDB 5.5 server remotely, and I get:

> Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.1.1' (111)

(where 192.168.1.1 represents a public IPv4).

I don't understand why because there are no restrictions (i.e. MySQL side, iptables/firewalld, etc).

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES like 'bind_address';
Empty set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> select user,host from mysql.user where user='root';
+------+-----------+
| user | host      |
+------+-----------+
| root | %         |
| root | 127.0.0.1 |
| root | ::1       |
+------+-----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]>


[root@rdns1 ~]# ss -lntp | grep 3306
LISTEN     0      50           *:3306                     *:*                   users:(("mysqld",pid=16254,fd=14))
[root@rdns1 ~]#
```

Comment: Is MariaDB listening at all? One way to check is running `sudo ss -lntp | grep 3306` on the server. By default, it only listens at 127.0.0.1; you need to set configuration variable `bind-address` to change this.

Comment: @berndbausch:

[root@rdns1 ~]# ss -lntp | grep 3306
LISTEN     0      50           *:3306                     *:*                   users:(("mysqld",pid=16254,fd=14))
[root@rdns1 ~]#

Comment: The output looks garbled. Can you add it to the question and format it as code? The error number is 111, which is "connection refused". Either a firewall between client and server sends the error, or the server's kernel. In the latter case, it means that no process listens at 192.168.1.1:3306.

Comment: @berndbausch - I've added it to the question

Comment: This means MariaDB is indeed listening. I suspect that connection requests don't arrive at that server or that the server blocks them with a firewall (although you say there is none). To check whether traffic reaches the server, run `tcpdump -i any port 3306` on it and try to connect from the client.